# SUM column of related tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've two tables, packages:

`id, ..., price` fields

and users:

`id, ..., package_id`

so every user has a package (users can have same package) that has a price.

and I want to calculate the SUM of the `price` of all users, how is the best way to do this? preferably with only SQL. Having in mind that users table can have ~1m of users.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(price_x_user)
FROM (
    SELECT price AS price_x_user,
        users.id
    FROM users
    INNER JOIN packages ON packages.id = users.package_id
) AS users_package
```

Comment: You need to group by when using a grouping function like sum

Answer (score 0):

```
Select id, SUM(price) from users t
Left join package p on p.id = t.id
group by t.id
```

When using a grouping function like SUM, it is required to group by.

Comment: You mean `... on p.id = t.package_id ...` right ? But anyway it not works... for any reason p is NULL. In the current database all users has `package_id = 17` and the package with `id = 17` exists